# Simulink scope changes value depending on simulation time

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, matlab, simulink

I am making a co-simulation in Simulink for a circuit that I made in ORCAD, and I saw this problem that appears: If I put the final stop time for simulation 10s the signal looks like in first picture where you can see that the distance between those two points is 0.787ms. When I change the stop time simulation at 30s the signal looks like in the second picture. As you can see the distance is shorter now: 0.389.7ms.

I am thinking that the whole scope window has a limited number of points and if I increase the stop time simulation it tries to fit the signal in those numbers of points but I am not sure. I would like to know your opinion. BTW I didn't let for the second picture the full simulation until 30s.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In scope settings, under some tab there is a setting called data history or something similar. Keep that a large number. The default value is usually to small. There is also option in that same tab to keep the full data. If you have enough RAM, try that also. Apart from the above there is a button in the tool bar to zoom out so that the full plot is visible. Sometimes the default zoom level doesn't show the full time duration.

Comment: Don't measure time between two samples. Simulink by default uses variable sample time. You may not be measuring the smallest sample of the simulation if you measure it using the scope.

Comment: Instead force simulink to limit the sample time to sone value by setting the *maxstep* parameter in the *model configuration parameters* dialogue box. Please add a screenshot shot of the model configuration parameters dialogue box and scope settings dialogue box by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well it certainly looks like the sample intervals are too large and unequal. It seems like the noise BW exceeds the Nyquist rate or something like that causing aliasing and changes in output data intervals over time.

- The 1st simulation has intervals of 0.1 and 0.9s while 2nd is 0.4 and 0.6 s.
  (0.3897 rounded to 0.4).
- Both average 1.0 second for 2 consecutive intervals and both have the largest change after the shorter interval in the 1st but after the longer interval in the 2nd.
- at the moment, there is insufficient detail to recommend any fix for your accelerometer data except the output data BW is much lower than the signal or noise BW.

Comment: OP needs to add a naximum timestep, or some sampler along the way, forcing a timestep.

Comment: Simulink computation time can be quite large depending how it’s done, but the Nyquist filter and digital filtering was my concern.